# Getting A Boolean Value From Activity In Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

It's weird this question hasn't been asked yet.

I need to check phone storage in my activity and get the returned value in my fragment

```
/*MainActivity*/
boolean hasLowStorage(){
    IntentFilter lowStorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
    return registerReceiver(null, lowStorageFilter) != null;
}
```

When calling a void method from an activity, we do this:

```
 /*fragment*/
((MainActivity) getActivity()).yourMethod();
```

How do we call for the value in the boolean case from the fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change scope of method to public and try again.

// MainActivity

```
public boolean hasLowStorage(){
        IntentFilter lowStorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
        return registerReceiver(null, lowStorageFilter) != null;
    }
```

//Fragment

```
    boolean bolValue = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hasLowStorage();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean yourValue = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hasLowStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it public static like this

```
 /*MainActivity*/
 public static boolean hasLowStorage(){
 IntentFilter lowStorageFilter = new 
 IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
 return registerReceiver(null, lowStorageFilter) != null;
 }
```

And call it like

```
 boolean yourValue = 
 MainActivity.hasLowStorage();
```

Happy coding :)